# what does wedge or carrot mean in a matrix context

Tags: matrices

While reading about coordinate transformations. I came across this

$\Omega^{\gamma}_{\beta,\alpha}=[\omega^{\gamma}_{\beta,\alpha}\wedge]$

What does the caret (or wedge) mean? In the book it looks more like a caret than a wedge.

[image: image from source]

Taken from Groves, Paul D Principles of GNSS, Inertial, And Multisensor Integrated Navigation Systems 2nd ed p. 45.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Math SX! Carrot? What's up, doc?

Comment: Linking to the particular thing you were reading can help (or a picture of it).  Offhand, $\wedge$ is used for the [exterior product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra) in vector spaces

Answer (score 0):

The $\Omega$ matrix acts the same as if you take the outer product of the $\omega$ vector. Symbolically $\Omega A = \omega \wedge A$

or

$\Omega = [ \omega \wedge]$

Comment: What do you mean by "outer product"? The product of a matrix and a vector is a vector, but the exterior product of two vectors is a bivector, not a vector.

Comment: @mr_e_man: Yes, but they're canonically isomorphic under the Hodge star.  In a physics context, use the metric to raise/lower the indices.

Answer (score 0):

The [exterior algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra) is a way of representing oriented subspaces of a vector space. Given two vectors $v, w$, the quantity $v\wedge w$ is called a *bivector* and represents an oriented plane. In three dimensions (and only three dimensions), the space of bivectors is also three dimensional. If $e_1, e_2, e_3$ is a basis of vectors, then
$$
  1,\; e_1,\; e_2,\; e_3,\; e_2\wedge e_3,\; e_3\wedge e_1,\; e_2\wedge e_3,\; e_1\wedge e_2\wedge e_3
$$
is a basis for the exterior algebra. If we let $F$ be the identification
$$
  F(e_2\wedge e_3) = e_1,\quad F(e_3\wedge e_1) = e_2,\quad F(e_2\wedge e_3) = e_3,
$$
and extend linearly to all bivectors, then $F(v\wedge w) = v\times w$ is exactly the cross product of vectors $v$ and $w$.

So assuming $\omega_{\alpha\beta}^\gamma$ are vectors, then they're saying that
$$
  \Omega_{\alpha\beta}^\gamma v = F(\omega_{\alpha\beta}^\gamma\wedge v) = \omega_{\alpha\beta}^\gamma\times v
$$
for any vector $v$ (which is perfectly fine since $\wedge$ and $F$ are linear), and so $\Omega_{\alpha\beta}^\gamma$ has components
$$
  (\Omega_{\alpha\beta}^\gamma v)_{ij} = e_i\cdot F(\omega_{\alpha\beta}^\gamma\wedge e_j) = e_i\cdot(\omega_{\alpha\beta}^\gamma\times e_j).
$$